# Install libtorrent(rasterbar) along with boost 1.53

Tags: c++, linux, boost, dependencies, libtorrent

I have `libboost1.53-dev` installed in my system. when I am trying to install `libtorrent-rasterbar-dev`, it won't let me do it because of a dependency conflict. `libtorrent-rasterbar` depends on `libboost-serialization1.49` on my system (ubuntu 13.04 64bit with multiarch support). I have other libraries depends on `libboost1.53` and I really need to install `rasterbar`. It is a classic [Dependency Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) - conflicting dependencies problem!

What solution do you prefer?

Comment: chances are that you may be able to just drop that dependency (it it's a new enough version of libtorrent at least)

Comment: @Arvid how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know how the package system on ubuntu works. My understanding is that it's using debian packages, so maybe there's a repository of .deb files somewhere describing these dependencies. I believe the maintainer of the debian package for libtorrent is associated with the qbittorrent project, you might ask around there.